# My widget does not appear in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter

My widget gets like this in release mode (does not appear):

[image: My widget gets like this in release mode (does not appear)]

and get like this in debug mode:

[image: and get like this in debug mode]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be getting this error due to incorrect use of a widget in the widget tree. For example, the Expanded widget may have been used incorrectly.

Comment: Note that answers ought not ask for more information - they should stand alone as much as possible. If you need to ask for clarifications, please add a comment under the question. Remember that answers are best if they can help many people in the future, not just one.